# C# Webservice to return entire SOAPBody as XML

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I'm patching together a C# Webservice which reads predefined SOAP responses from XML files. We're using this to mock a productive web service. The XML files contain the nodes directly child to ''. However, my current code adds a node to '', thus resulting in a wrong format.

What I got:

```
 <soap:Body>
   <Security_AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://xml.tempuri.com/">
     <Security_AuthenticateReply xmlns="http://xml.tempuri.com/VLSSLR_06_1_1A">
       <processStatus>
       ...
       </processStatus>
     </Security_AuthenticateReply>
   </Security_AuthenticateReply>
 </soap:Body>
```

What we need:

```
 <soap:Body>
   <Security_AuthenticateReply xmlns="http://xml.tempuri.com/VLSSLR_06_1_1A">
     <processStatus>
     ...
     </processStatus>
   </Security_AuthenticateReply>
 </soap:Body>
```

My code:

```
   [SoapDocumentMethod(Action = "http://webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWABOAAI/VLSSLQ_06_1_1A",
          RequestNamespace = "http://xml.amadeus.com/VLSSLQ_06_1_1A",
          RequestElementName = "Security_Authenticate",
          ResponseNamespace = "http://xml.amadeus.com/VLSSLR_06_1_1A",
          ResponseElementName = "Security_AuthenticateReply")]
   [WebMethod]
   [return: XmlAnyElement]
   [SoapHeader("sessionId", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.Out)]
   public XmlDocument Security_Authenticate()
   {
      .. some file magic here ...
      XmlDocument rp = getFile("Security_AuthenticateReply.xml");
      return rp;
   }
```

I'm hoping for some directive which tells C# to drop one of the nodes. As an alternative, I guess I'll have to extract all child nodes and return those.

Comment: Just tried the option with returning a List<XmlNode>, which leads to a <ArrayOfXmlNode>, so that's not an option.